Randomly replacing black balls in an urn
Question:
There is in an urn with initially only $N$ black balls in it. At the end of each day $10\%$ of the balls in the urn are chosen at random and are replaced with exactly that many red balls, resulting in the total number of balls in the urn being always $N$. What is the expected number of days it will take for there to be no black balls left in the urn?
I can't get past the fact that the expected value here could be infinite, as it is possible on the second, third, etc days to only select the 10% of red balls added after the first day.
Note: $N$ is both sufficiently large such that $10\%$ of $N$ is always an integer and $N$ is also always a multiple of $10$.

Is there a way to figure this out without resorting to monte-carlo simulations?

$N$ just has to be a multiple of $10$ so that you can pick exactly $10%$ of the balls. The number of balls in the urn never changes.

@DavidK  correct, hence the statement that  "N is sufficiently large such that 10%
of N is always an integer." but i'll update the question to be more precise.

No, if $N=10000000005$ then you cannot draw exactly $10%$ of the balls. But $N=10$ is fine. There is no "large enough" such that $0.1N$ is always an integer. Possibly you're supposed to consider $N$ large enough that you can approximate the problem with a continuous distribution.

aah I see. I'll make another update, hopefully we can get to the crux of the problem soon. :D

I think the larger $N$ is, the larger the expected number of days is. Where did this problem come from?

This is the coupon collector problem, where you take  $\frac N{10}$ coupons at a time.

@DavidK that is true, when doing simulations the large N is the longer it takes on average, and it seems like increase is somewhat exponential, which makes sense as the less black balls there are the less likely they will be chosen for replacement.  I think it's  $(N-10)/N$

"the expected value here could be infinite, as it is possible … to only select the 10% of red balls added after the first day" — but that happens with probability 0, so doesn't contribute to the expected value.

Consider this similar situation: how many times do I have to flip a coin before I can expect to get Heads?  The answer is 2. But isn't it possible that I might flip a million times and not get heads?  Yes, but only with very small probability, so that it barely affects the expected value. And isn't it possible I might never get heads?  That happens with probability 0 and doesn't affect the expected value at all.

@MJD that does make sense, but as the number of red balls exceeds 50% the probability of selection a black ball in the 10% selection decreases exponentially hence less chance of replacing the remaining black balls, is that not the case?

Every individual black ball has a $10%$ chance of being replaced each day. We can be sure that the expected value isn't greater than $10N$.

I wonder what kind of answer is expected for this question. Exact probabilities for large $N$ seem difficult (perhaps too difficult) to compute. Do we want an approximate formula? An asymptotic approximation? Big-O?

@PennyDreudter "the probability of selection a black ball in the 10% selection decreases exponentially"  No, it never decreases below $\frac1{10}$. Each remaining black ball has a 10% chance of being selected. Even when there is only one black ball among a million red ones, there is still a 10% chance each day of replacing the one black ball.

Let $m,n$ be a positive integers with $m < n$.

An urn contains $n$ balls, initially all black.

On each day, a random selection of $m$ balls are removed from the urn, to be replaced by $m$ red balls.

For $0\le b\le n$, let $e(b)$ be the expected number of days until there are no black balls remaining in the urn, assuming the urn currently contains $b$ black balls.

Here are some example values of $e(b)$, obtained via recursion, implemented in Maple . . .
\begin{array}
{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n&m&b&e(b)\\
\hline
10&1&10&
{\small{\frac{7381}{252}}}\approx 29.28968254
\\
\hline
20&2&20&
{\small{\frac{645315821032049}{18278449721532}}}\approx 35.30473486
\\
\hline
30&3&30&
{\small{\frac{501153527907235775623478324759812273919}{12876244117029357264217694131168633920}}}\approx 38.92078492
\\
\hline
\end{array}
For reference, here's the Maple code . . .



Some explanatory remarks . . .

The variables $b,r$ represent the number of black, red balls, respectively, in the urn at the start of a given day (before the removal and replacement operations for the day).

The variable $k$ represents the number of black balls in the random selection of $m$ balls for the given day.

For each potential value of $k$, the variable $p$ represents the probability of the occurrence of that value of $k$.

Explicitly we have
$$
p
=
\frac
{
\binom{b}{k}
\binom{r}{m-k}
}
{
\binom{n}{m}
}
$$
The value of $e(b)$ is then set to the sum of the contributions to $e(b)$ for each value of $k$.

would it be possible to elaborate on the recursive formulation. perhaps something before the "Here are some example values of e(b)" section.

@Penny Dreudter: I've edited in some explanatory remarks.

If we remove 10% of the balls and replace them with red balls and there is no preference to which balls are selected to be replaced then in expectation we expect 10% of the black balls to be removed at each step (and 10% of the red balls for that matter as well). The population of black balls will decrease by 10% in expectation every single day so the expectation of black balls given $d$ days would be:
$$E[b] = N \cdot 0.9^d$$
This is just the expectancy at a given day though, not the expected number of days. The expectancy only ever approaches 0, but the actual expected number of days will be a discrete number.
I think a good analogy would be in medicine how there is a half life to each drug. It’s common to say that a drug leaves your system after 5 half lives, but in reality only the vast majority of it actually has.
I think a reasonable way to approach this is find the number of days, such that $E[b] = \frac{1}{N}$ and then for sufficiently large $N$ the expected number of trials that 1 ball is randomly selected from 10% buckets is geometric and has expectancy of 10 trials. So we have:
$$
0.9^d = \frac{1}{N}
$$
$$
\ln(0.9^d) = \ln\left( \frac{1}{N} \right)
$$
$$
d \ln(0.9) = -\ln(N)
$$
$$
d = \frac{-\ln(N)}{\ln(0.9)}
$$
$$
E[d] = \frac{-\ln(N)}{\ln(0.9)} + 10
$$

$N$ is a finite number, so the minimum fraction of black balls is $1/N$. The actual fraction cannot approach $0$ indefinitely. No matter how large $N$ is at the start, after some number of days the population of black balls will reduce to a small enough number that this becomes a finite process.

@DavidK I agree that there is a point at which it approaches 0, but this is kind of similar to a brainteaser interview question called “place or take”.    https://www.quantguide.io/questions/place-or-take . In the question it describes how you have at most 100 moves, but it doesn’t matter even if you have an unlimited number of moves, you can only take 1-(1/2)^take proportion of the balls placed and this clearly approaches 1 when number of takes approaches infinity but I don’t think there’s not a discrete number where we just say in expectancy now it’s 100%.

@DavidK never mind, you’re right. Changing my answer now

@Evan can you explain the source of final +10 ?

@PennyDreudter my goal was to find the expected number of days until there was 1 black balls left (when the ratio of black balls is 1/N) and then for sufficiently large N the probability of a specific ball being selected when you randomly select 10% of the N balls is 1/10. The expected number of trials until success for something with 1/10 chance is just 10 since this is geometric so we take the EV of until we get to 1 black ball remaining plus 10 for the final remaining one. This is (almost certainly) not exact, but for sufficiently large N I think it's ~reasonable~.
